# Namespace name and type name conflict

Tags: c#

Is it possible to make the following code valid in C# without changing my namespace or type name. I'm wondering if there is a trick or keyword around this problem?

```
namespace NS
{
    public class Foo { }
}

namespace NS.Foo
{
    public class Bar { }
}
```

The error I'm getting is "The namespace 'NS' already contains a definition for 'Foo'".

Comment: Don't do this: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2010/03/09/do-not-name-a-class-the-same-as-its-namespace-part-one.aspx

Comment: Wwwwwww, no, you don't want to do that. It will annoy you, and anyone else using that codebase, in no time.

Comment: @Jason: your link refers to a class being the same name as its *enclosing* namespace (that is, class `NS.NS` or `NS.Foo.Foo`), which is not the same as the scenario in the question - which is a namespace and a class at the same level of the hierarchy having the same name.

Comment: @Jason: I saw that MSDN page before and it doesn't actually solve this particular problem. He basically says "avoid this" in part 4 of the article.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Essentially, no there isn't.  Even if you could somehow resolve the immediate ambiguity, this problem goes all the way down: what happens if you declare a property of `Foo` named `Bar`?

Rename one of your `Foo`s.

Answer (score 4):

No - Imagine having a subclass in `Foo` called `Bar`:

```
namespace NS
{
    public class Foo { public class Bar {} }
}

namespace NS.Foo
{
    public class Bar { }
}
```

How can you ever tell the difference if one does: `new NS.Foo.Bar()`?

Answer (score 0):

No - there's no way to disambiguate from `NS.Foo` the *namespace* and `NS.Foo` the *class*.